# File path not resolving in javascript from typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, path

I am using @ symbol to import the files in typescript.
The tsconfig.json file code:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "target": "ES6",
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "lib": ["ES2018"],
        "outDir": "dist/",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "strict": true,
        "sourceMap": false,
        "useUnknownInCatchVariables": false,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./typings"],
        "paths": {
            "@src/*": ["src/*"],
            "@api/*": ["src/api/*"],
            "@config/*": ["src/config/*"],
            "@database/*": ["src/database/*"],
            "@middlewares/*": ["src/middlewares/*"],
            "@utils/*": ["src/utils/*"],
            "@validators/*": ["src/validators/*"]
        }
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules/**/*"]
}
```

When I compile typescript to javascript it uses the path with @ symbol something like this: `const env_config_1 = require("@config/env/env.config");` which is not working as javascript does not understand @.

I have tried different solutions like using the packages named [tsc-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsc-alias), tscpaths and restarting the typescript server in IDE but it still converts path in javascript with @ symbol.

The build command using tsc-alias package: `"build": "tsc -p tsconfig.json && tsc-alias -p tsconfig.json"`